# Why don't ZF2 form renderers rely on the input filter for telling if a field is required?

Tags: zend-framework2

What do you reckon is the reasoning between Zend Framework 2 allowing setting if a field is required in both the input filter and the form field's HTML5 attribute? In my application I want to have red asterisks displayed next to field labels to indicate a field is required and not necessarily have the "required" attribute set on the fields, but it doesn't hurt. I understand that this separation maybe this is useful in some cases that I can't currently think of, but I think it'd be enough to just rely on whether an input filter says a field's required. Because of that I started writing my own form renderer that wouldn't require me to write that a field is required twice (for the input filter and the HTML5 attribute), but maybe there are sound reasons for why these are separate and I should rather take the time to set both the input filter required property and the required attribute? (But I see this as a sort of violation of the DRY rule.)

Comment: What component are you talking about? About the element renderer?

Configuring the InputFilter component and setting your form's element attributes are two different things.